# Why am I not able to create break points in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, osx-mountain-lion

Whenever I try to create a break point in Eclipse it has a line through the break point icon and the code does not stop here. Any one know what's going on?

I am on OSX Mountain Lion, and Eclipse Juno 64bit.

[image: BreakPoint]

Comment: You'd better ask on stackoverflow, but basically that means the breakpoint was not sucessfully. Usually because the debugger failed to attach or the line number does not exist in the running code. If the code is not Java, it's also possible that you put break points on unstoppable lines.

Comment: Got down voted on Stackoverflow. This happens before I run anything so it is not related to debugger attaching and the language is java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable eclipse breakpoints . You can do that in Breakpoint view

[image]